# CodeIgniter - Delete file, pathing issue

Tags: codeigniter

I have 3 folders in my root, "application", "system", and "uploads". In application/controllers/mycontroller.php I have this line of code.

```
delete_files("../../uploads/$file_name");
```

The file does not get deleted and I have tried a number of pathing options like ../ and ../../../ any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$file_name` is a variable. You should concatenate it to your own string in order to execute the function:

```
delete_files("../../uploads/" . $file_name);
```

**EDIT:**

Make sure that this sentence:

```
echo base_url("uploads/" . $file_name);
```

Is echoing a valid path. If the answer is YES, try this:

```
$this->load->helper("url");
delete_files(base_url("uploads/" . $file_name));
```

Supposing that your "uploads" folder is in your root directory.

**EDIT 2:**

Using `unlink` function:

```
$this->load->helper("url");
unlink(base_url("uploads/" . $file_name));
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just changed my code to reflect yours, but the file does still not get deleted.

Comment: Okay so when I echo I get localhost/Site/uploads/image.jpeg. That is the correct path to the image but when I try..  `delete_files(base_url("uploads/" . $file_name));` it does the same thing as before, just runs through the rest of the code like it completely ignores that line.

Comment: Another way to remove a file from PHP is using `unlink` function. I'm going to edit my answer again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help. Now it throws an error Message: unlink(): http does not allow unlinking. Hmmm

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with folder's permission. Check it if "uploads" folder has permissions to remove files. If not, change it and try again your code.

Comment: Would that be an issue even if I am working off of MAMP localhost?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16425/discussion-between-fran-verona-and-staysee)

Comment: do delete_files() still works? I'm having an error  Call to undefined function delete_files()

Answer (score 6):

Use the FCPATH constant provided to you by CodeIgniter for this.

```
unlink(FCPATH . '/uploads/' . $filename);
```

`base_url()` generates HTTP urls, and cannot be used to generate filesystem paths. This is why you must use one of the CI path constants. They are defined in the front controller file (index.php).

The three ones you would use are:

- `FCPATH` - path to front controller, usually index.php
- `APPPATH` - path to application folder
- `BASEPATH` - path to system folder.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.. this just a very simple solution to your problem..
If you notice CI has there on defining of base_path to your directory e.g. in the upload library's config:

```
$imagePath = './picture/Temporary Profile Picture/';

$config['upload_path'] = $imagePath;

$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';

$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

if you notice the upload_path is './picture/Temporary Profile Picture/'

so if you want to delete a file from a directory all you have to do is use unlink() function.

```
unlink($imagePath . $file_name);
```

or

```
@unlink($imagePath . $file_name);
```

Enjoy..^^

Answer (score 1):

This code was working for me. Try this in your Model or Controller. Change the file path according to yours.

> file path -->> project_name/assets/uploads/file_name.jpg

```
public function delete_file()
{
    $file = 'file_name.jpg';
    $path = './assets/uploads/'.$file;
    unlink($path);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this code:

```
$imagepath = $config['upload_path'];
unlink($imagepath . $images);
```

or

```
delete_files($imagepath . $images);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function deleteContent($id)
 {  
    $this->db->where('Filename',$id);
    $this->db->delete('tableName',array('Filename'=>$id));
    if (unlink("upload/folderName/".$id)) 
    {
      redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
    }
  }
```

Comment: By using redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);  you will be not facing path issue.