# Cannot unlink file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload, unlink

In my project I have a folder **secure** in root. The project package looks like:

```
application 
secure
system 
...........
```

Inside secure folder I am uploading some images on form submit using

```
$config1['upload_path'] = './secure/';
$ext = end(explode(".", $_FILES['thumb_image']['name']));
$config1['file_name'] = time().$_FILES['thumb_image']['name'];
$config1['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|gif|bmp|jpe|tiff|tif';
$this->load->library('upload', $config1);
$this->upload->initialize($config1);
$this->upload->do_upload('thumb_image');
```

and it is working properly. Now while on editing the details, using another form, if I am uploading a new image instead of the current image file, I want to unlink the current one and then upload new file.

For this I am using the code:

```
unlink(base_url("secure/".$data['row']->videothumbnail));
```

I also tried with

```
unlink('/secure/'.$data['row']->videothumbnail);
```

where `$data['row']->videothumbnail)` is the current image file from database. New file is successfully uploaded. But old file is not getting unlinked. I have set the permission of secure folder to `777`. But the images are uploaded with read only permission. Is it because of this, it is not getting unlinked?

Can anyone help me to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks i missed . before /secure.

Comment: You could try do a chmod on the file after the upload to change the permissions

Comment: if dir path wrong then `unlink` function show warning, can you show warning??

Comment: it is now working..the problem was I missed . before the /secure/ path..

Comment: You can have a look at this url

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12320589/codeigniter-delete-file-pathing-issue

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Set the permission dynamically using:

```
@chmod('./secure/'.$data['row']->videothumbnail, 0777);
```

then try unlink:

```
@unlink('./secure/'.$data['row']->videothumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try echoing the path that you are providing  to unlink function.

It should be something like this:

```
base_url()."secure/".$data['row']->videothumbnail;
```

Comment: that still won't help because u cannot unlink from a URL!

Comment: Um - no it isn't... `base_url` will provide you `HTTP` path, the `unlink` function required directory path...

Answer (score 0):

First Load the `$this->load->helper("file")` and then unlink it

```
unlink("secure/".$data['row']->videothumbnail);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue even after setting the right permission on the folder. But the following code worked for me.

```
unlink(realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads').'/'.$ImageName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` instead of `base_url`

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->helper("file") 
unlink(base_url('folder/file.ext'));
```

location:

\app\controller

\system\libraries

**folder\file.ext**

Answer (score 0):

```
$unlinkUrl = "secure/".$data['row']->videothumbnail;
if(file_exists($unlinkUrl)){
    unlink($unlinkUrl);
}
else{
    echo $unlinkUrl." is not available";    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just making a stupid mistake.

- Firstly, the first param of `unlink` should be a relative path or absolute path, but `base_url` function will return you a path contains domain name, HOW CAN YOU DELETE A FILE ON REMOTE SERVER ?
- Secondly, `'/secure/'.$data['row']->videothumbnail` here is not a relative path but a absolute path

YOU MUST change it into `/the/absolute/path/to/secure/` or `./the/relative/path/to/secure/` (**DO NOT MISS THE DOT**)

Answer (score 0):

use this to unlink

```
$oldthumb = "secure/".$data['row']->videothumbnail;
@unlink($oldthumb);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($rowAffected > 0) {
                if ($isMediaUpload)
                    if (file_exists('./uploads/' . $this->input->post('img_url')))
                        unlink('./uploads/' . $this->input->post('img_url'));
                            redirect('/admin/configration', 'location');
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Though i came in late but someone might need this .

```
unlink(FCPATH."secure/".$data['row']->videothumbnail)

**FCPATH** - path to front controller, usually index.php
**APPPATH** - path to application folder
**BASEPATH** - path to system folder.
```