# Codeigniter - unlink delete file not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem with unlink or delete file with codeigniter

Here is my controller

```
function delete($id_post=''){
    $this->home_model->delete($id_post);
    $this->session->set_flashdata('danger', "Your photo has been deleted...");
    redirect("home");
}
```

And this is my model

```
function delete($id_post=''){
    $file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='$id_post'");
    unlink(base_url("uploads/" . $file_name));
    $sql  = "DELETE FROM post WHERE id_post=?";
    $outp = $this->db->query($sql,array($id_post));
}
```

**Doc** is the name of column that contain image.

If i click button delete, it delete a data in database and works successfully but not the image in file folder. I want, when i delete a data it is also delete image in file folder uploads. Uploads folder is in the root aplication system.

Any answer?

Many thanks...

Comment: The query() function returns a database result object. So check your code. Try to print $file_name before unlink and see the result

Comment: like this `return $filename;`?

Comment: like: print_r($filename); die; before unlink

Comment: replace this $file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='$id_post'")->row()->doc;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query() function returns a database result object. So replace your model code with:

```
function delete($id_post=''){
    $file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='$id_post'");
    $row = $file_name->row();
    $file_name = $row['doc'];
    unlink(base_url("uploads/" . $file_name));
    $sql  = "DELETE FROM post WHERE id_post=?";
    $outp = $this->db->query($sql,array($id_post));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you does not fetch your result resource.
Use:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='$id_post'");
$row = $query->result();
$file_name = str_replace('localhost/latihan/uploads/','',$this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='".$id_post."'")->row()->doc);
unlink("uploads/" . $file_name);
```

Comment: it returning an error like this Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array, because $row maybe?

Comment: `var_dump($row);` Whats inside it?

Comment: `Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\latihan\application\modules\home\models\home_model.php on line 241`... The line 241 is `$file_name = $row[0]['doc'];`

Comment: Errr.. And what if `$row['doc']` only, not `$row[0]['doc']`?

Comment: Oh, I see now, somebody edited my code. Please after `$file_name = ....` says a `var_dump($file_name);` and show me the result.

Comment: $file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='".$id_post."'")->row()->doc;

Comment: i add `var_dump($file_name)` below `$file_name=` but it still not delete image file

Comment: Ok, I've just want to know, what is the output of the `var_dump` Please show me that. `var_dump` is just dump out the content of variable.

Comment: Just right after `$file_name = ....`. It will output anywhere. `var_dump($file_name); die();`  It will show, whats in the `$file_name` and terminate the script. This is how should debug on the output.

Comment: The Output is `Message: Undefined index: doc And NULL`

Comment: Ok, so this means, we did not fetch the query. Try this, what @Arun sad, and replace the `$file_name = ...` line buy this: `$file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='".$id_post."'")->row()->doc;` And now tell me, what `var_dump` says.

Comment: So now you are close. I think, now just you neeed to replace the `'localhost/latihan/uploads/'` to nothing, and unlink the file in the uploads directory. From here, I think, now you can figure out. remove the `var_dump` and `die`

Comment: And do not add URL to the file, when you want to delete it, you can delete it on filesystem, not through the web.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->load->helper("url");
unlink(base_url("uploads/" . $file_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
$file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='$id_post'");
```

please replace this

```
$file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='".$id_post."'")->row()->doc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function delete($id_post=''){
    $file_name = $this->db->query("SELECT doc FROM post WHERE post.id_post='$id_post'");

    $res = $this->db->result();  // this returns an object of all results
    $row = $res[0];            
    $filename = $row['doc']; // get the file name from array
    // do the delete after getting the filename
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can use this using directory path

```
unlink(FCPATH.'uploads/yourfile');
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to delete your file with URL address you have to specifiy local document address like this:

```
unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."uploads/".$filename);
```

here is similiar question:

[Cannot unlink file in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803551/cannot-unlink-file-in-codeigniter)